# how to make React Native and Graphql app with authentication or signup, sign in and sign out

Tags: react-native, authentication, graphql

How to create an app using React Native and Graphql. The app just need to included function user account with authentication (signup, sign in and sign out)

Comment: need example for easy to understand

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code. please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

connect with aws amplify, then type 'add auth' in console